# Как проиндексировать только те модели\строки, где some_field=some_value?

Tags: django, haystack

Я использую django-oscar + Solr + haystack.

```
*===============================================================================================================*
|   id  | partner_sku|price_currency|price_excl_tax|num_in_stock|date_created|date_updated|partner_id|product_id|
|"10451"|"S0010436"  |  "USD"       |   74.00      |    20      |'some_date' |'some_date' |     1    | 5992     |
|"10452"|"S0010436"  |  "USD"       |   80.00      |     0      |'some_date' |'some_date' |     2    | 5992     |
*===============================================================================================================*
```

Я хочу проиндексировать только строки, где partner_id=2. `index_queryset` ниже не индексирует так как хочу, так как все партнеры продолжают индексироваться.

```
class ProductIndexes(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
            document=True, use_template=True,
            template_name='search/indexes/cpu/item_text.txt')

    upc = indexes.CharField(model_attr="upc", null=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', null=True)

    # Fields for faceting
    product_class = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    category = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    partner = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    price = indexes.FloatField(null=True, faceted=True)
    vendor = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    rating = indexes.IntegerField(null=True, faceted=True)
    num_in_stock = indexes.BooleanField(null=True, faceted=True)

    # Spelling suggestions
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    date_created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_created')
    date_updated = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_updated')

    def get_model(self):
        return get_model('catalogue', 'Product')

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(stockrecords__partner_id=2).order_by('-num_in_stock')
```

Как сделать нужную мне индексацию?

`python manage.py rebuild_index` запустить не забыл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый правильный код должен выглядеть вот так (см. комментарии в коде):

```
class ProductIndexes(CelerySearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.EdgeNgramField(
            document=True, use_template=True,
            template_name='search/indexes/cpu/item_text.txt')

    upc = indexes.CharField(model_attr="upc", null=True)
    title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title', null=True)

    # ДОБАВЛЕНО НОВОЕ ПОЛЕ
    local_stock = indexes.IntegerField(null=True, faceted=False)

    # Fields for faceting
    product_class = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    category = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    partner = indexes.MultiValueField(null=True, faceted=True)
    price = indexes.FloatField(null=True, faceted=True)
    vendor = indexes.CharField(null=True, faceted=True)
    rating = indexes.IntegerField(null=True, faceted=True)
    num_in_stock = indexes.BooleanField(null=True, faceted=True)

    # Spelling suggestions
    suggestions = indexes.FacetCharField()

    date_created = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_created')
    date_updated = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='date_updated')

    def get_model(self):
        return get_model('catalogue', 'Product')

    # МЕТОД ИЗМЕНЕН    
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().browsable.order_by('-date_updated')

    # ДОБАВЛЕН НОВЫЙ МЕТОД
    def prepare_local_stock(self, obj):
        local_stock = StockRecord.objects.filter(partner_id=2, product=obj)
        if local_stock.exists():
            local_stock = local_stock[0].num_in_stock
        else:
            local_stock = 0
        return int(local_stock)
```

В файле `search_handler.py` (относится к `django-oscar`, отвечает за вывод товара в категории) нужно указать, что сортировка идет по полю `local_stock`, т.е. прописываем `return sqs.order_by('-local_stock')`